# JAVA storage options

Tags: java, data-structures, storage

Ok I have a reservation object which stores all details of event for which the reservation is made. Now for an event to be approved, it has to be viewed by three different users. Each time a reservation is made, those three should be assigned. Now when the reservation request is reviewed by any of the three, and a response is given, that user has to be marked that he responded.

I need to store the following like

```
User1 ----> Response & Type & ID
User2 ----> Response & Type & ID
User3 ----> Response & Type & ID
```

So when user1 for example reviews and accepts, then i access this way

```
 reservationInstance.approvers.user1.response(true);
```

just an example of course and not practical code. What would the best suggestion be? and can there be code provided for clarification? I will work on its customization

Comment: *"and can there be code provided for clarification?"*  Sure, post any short code sample you like.

Comment: @AndrewThompson hmmm I can't post code because all I have are multiple classes created to fulfill the above hence am asking for a possible shortcut than accessing all those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Reservation doesn't have to have a List/Set of approvers, one is enough. since you mentioned:

> Now when the reservation request is reviewed by any of the three, and
>   a response is given, that user has to be marked that he responded.

Reservation could have an Approver attribute, which would be the Type User, to store which user has reviewed this reservation and gave response. In database layer, this can be a foreign key to User table.

If you want to find out which user (1,2 or3) has viewed. just `reservationInstance.getApprover().getUserId()`
(Assume your User class has a userId property.)

**EDIT**

to make it clear based on comments:

you have a Reservation class:

```
Reservation:
- Integer id
- User approver
- String content
- List<User> recievers
- String (could be enum) status (created, approved...etc.)
```

You have User class

```
User:
- Integer id
- String name
- String foo
- ...
```

if I understood your requirement right:

when a reservation instance was created, a set of Users as recievers were set. which means, those users will recieve the reservation. in your case, maybe 3 users. here you sent email, fax, sms whatever to them.

Then, say user2 (id=2), opened it, and approved this reservation. The reservation.approver will be set as User object(id=2). and status of this reservation (if there was a status requirement) will be changed to "Approved" or "Responsed"...

I don't know what's your exact requirement, however hope this helps.

Comment: So I have to keep a User class which I will instantiate with each reservation 3 times? What about array/lists? I really don't want to complicate the mapping in the database.

Comment: No, the Reservation.approver is null when a Reservation was created/instantiated. only if one user viewed(this is somthing to do with your business logic),  the user was set as approver of this Reservation instance. The mapping is not complicated at all. simply oneToMany relationship. Reservation (*) <--approver--> (1) User

Comment: Yes but the thing is the the users have to be pre-defined once the reservation is made. Emails will be sent out to them that a new reservation was made. Maybe u r right, I should just use a user class that encapsulates all the details?

Comment: @sys_debug see my EDIT in my answer. there I can use formatter. hope it helps.